# What is wrong with my PHP filtering system?

Tags: php

I have a simple filtering function for data that I'm receiving from POST, and for another variable (it will be part of the SESSION array, but in development is in an array of its own).  The POST data is handled by the function exactly as expected, whereas the other variable, `$sess['iid']`, ***always*** fails.  Why?

I can work around this, but I hate not to understand why it's happening.

The filtering function:

```
function filterNumber($fin) {
    if( ctype_digit( $fin ) ) {
    $fout = $fin;
    } else {
    $fout = 0;
    }
    return $fout;
}
```

I am strict about naming variables, so the POST array is transferred into `$dirty[]`, and then `$clean[]` (for entry into the database) is produced by applying the appropriate filter to `$dirty[]`.  The exact same sequence is applied to `$sess['iid']`.

Examples of each stage:

```
    $dirty['iid'] = $sess['iid'];
    $dirty['liverpool'] = $_POST['liverpool'];

    $clean['iid'] = filterNumber($dirty['iid']);
    $clean['liverpool'] = filterNumber($dirty['liverpool']);
```

The first step - `$sess['iid']` to `$dirty['iid]` - works, just as the POST variables do.

But the second, `$dirty['iid']` to `$clean['iid']` via `filterNumber()`, results in a value of 0, regardless of what I put into `$sess['iid']`.
This also happens if I eliminate the `$dirty['iid']` step.

Comment: Showcase a `var_dump()` of your `$dirty['iid']`.

Comment: What is **whatever**? It gives output as expected if `$dirty['iid']` has only digits

Comment: The numeric values must be only integers, it will not work with float. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Comment: "the other variable ( `$sess['iid']` ) always fails". It shouldn't *always* fail, there is nothing wrong with the code. However, what you expect the code to do may be different than what it *is* doing. e.g. what @psu says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function filterNumber($fin) {
    if( ctype_digit( $fin ) ) {
    $fout = $fin;
    } else {
    $fout = 0;
    }
    return $fout;
}

$tests = array(
    1,
    '1',
    '123',
    123,
    1.2,
    '1.2',
    'abc',
    true,
    false,
    null,
    new stdClass()
);

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo 'Testing: ' . var_export($test, true) . ' - result: ' . filterNumber($test);
}
```

Prints

```
Testing: 1 - result: 0
Testing: '1' - result: 1
Testing: '123' - result: 123
Testing: 123 - result: 0
Testing: 1.2 - result: 0
Testing: '1.2' - result: 0
Testing: 'abc' - result: 0
Testing: true - result: 0
Testing: false - result: 0
Testing: NULL - result: 0
Testing: stdClass::__set_state(array(
)) - result: 0
```

### Resources

- [var_export](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)
- [var-dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)
- [gettype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

Comment: This is as I expected.  If I change the input value to '1' rather than 1, the function says "yes".  Which must mean that the output from the database also are interpreted as 'x' rather than x (as they appear in my dump of variables). But **why** is this so?

Comment: The lesson I learn from this is that PHP treats **all** data retrieved from a database as a string, even when it is composed solely of digits and comes from an INT column in the DB. I think I need to adapt my variable dump function to show each variable's type as well as its value...

Comment: [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php) is actually dumping the type, I've updated the answer to include type boolean and object. `var_export` has some quirks e.g. it invokes [`__set_state()`](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state) on objects. You can also use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/function.var-dump.php). Also, keep in mind too that PHP also treats data superglobals such as GET and POST as strings too.